# WordPress page with several user editable text content

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WP and I'm trying to see which is the ***community approved* standard way** of having a page with several user editable content (text, images…). I'm thinking on pages with custom layouts (e.g: `homepage`) where I have a 12 cols row, then 4-4-4 one, an image, etc. Note: the layout might follow a columns layout or not (it could be an user editable random divs mess).

Are `custom fields` the way to go? Maybe there is *the* plugin?

Comment: Advanced Custom Fields is very good plugin [ACF](https://en.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Advanced Custom Fields, specifically the "Flexible Content" field, so you can add/remove blocks of content and move them up and down the page.

For total control of your page layout, then Beaver Builder would be the way to go.